# Unity drag and drop file to explorer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, drag-and-drop, ole, explorer

Im working on unity game tool, where you need to drag and drop file from explorer, process there, and drag and drop it back to explorer, notepad, paint or something else.

Problem: I cant drop file in explorer, or somewhere else, but I can "copy" file to empty space on left sidebar or scrollbar.

Can't copy filee and folders space: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4DBU.png
Can "copy" to empty space: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdaYD.png
Can "copy" to scrollbar: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rWDd.png

```
private void StartDrag()
{ 
    var data = new DataObject();
    var ls = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();
    ls.Add("C:/ExeMask.log");
    data.SetFileDropList(ls);

    OleInitialize(null);

    int[] array = new int[1];
    DoDragDrop(data, new DropSource(), (int)DragDropEffects.Copy, array);

    OleUninitialize();
}

[DllImport("ole32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern int OleInitialize(Action lpVoid);

[DllImport("ole32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern void OleUninitialize();

[DllImport("ole32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern int DoDragDrop(System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject dataObject, IOleDropSource dropSource, int allowedEffects, int[] finalEffect);
```

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("00000121-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IOleDropSource
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int OleQueryContinueDrag(int fEscapePressed, [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int grfKeyState);

    [PreserveSig]
    int OleGiveFeedback([In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int dwEffect);
}

public class DropSource : IOleDropSource
{
    public DropSource()
    {

    }

    public int OleQueryContinueDrag(int fEscapePressed, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int grfKeyState)
    {
        QueryContinueDragEventArgs qcdevent = null;
        bool escapePressed = fEscapePressed != 0;
        DragAction cancel = DragAction.Continue;
        if (escapePressed)
        {
            cancel = DragAction.Cancel;
        }
        else if ((((grfKeyState & 1) == 0) && ((grfKeyState & 2) == 0)) && ((grfKeyState & 0x10) == 0))
        {
            cancel = DragAction.Drop;
        }
        qcdevent = new QueryContinueDragEventArgs(grfKeyState, escapePressed, cancel);
        //this.peer.OnQueryContinueDrag(qcdevent);
        switch (qcdevent.Action)
        {
            case DragAction.Drop:
                return 0x40100;

            case DragAction.Cancel:
                return 0x40101;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public int OleGiveFeedback([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int dwEffect)
    {

        GiveFeedbackEventArgs gfbevent = new GiveFeedbackEventArgs((DragDropEffects)dwEffect, true);
        //this.peer.OnGiveFeedback(gfbevent);
        if (gfbevent.UseDefaultCursors)
        {
            return 0x40102;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

What I tried:

- Invoke and dont invoke OleInitialize and OleUninitialize
- Import exactly the same System.Windows.Forms.dll that WinForms used into unity (Failed to import due to no CIL found in unity)
- new Control().DoDragDrop - same result (but I used not exactly the same dll)
- Run app as admin.

Maybe there is some lib, that can start drag and drop without own gui - just invoke method and boom! drag and drop initiated?
I saw c++ solutions, but Im pretty bad with it.

Answer (score 0):

i tried to drag and drop images to the assetes and couldn't do it, then i turn to the folder with the name to the project on my computer opened the assets folder and draged the images there, and now they appear in the assets in unity